# Can I do structural refinement over a constructor?

Tags: scala

In my code I have something like this:

```
trait MyObj
trait Companion {
    type C <: MyObj
}
```

Then I have several pairs of classes and companion objects, where the companions extend Companion and the classes extend MyObj and define a constructor with a String parameter. I can't just make case classes inheriting from MyObj, cause then I can't make the companions extend Companion, but I end up repeating the same code in every companion:

```
class Foo(name: String) extends MyObj

object Foo extends Companion {
    type C = Foo
    def apply(name: String) = new Foo(name)
    // new C(name) works too
}
```

I'd like to move the implementation of apply to the Companion trait:

```
trait Companion {
    type C <: MyObj { def this(name: String) }
    def apply(name: String) = new C(name)
}
```

and now the inheriting objects just need to specify the type of C. But this doesn't compile. Is there any way of telling the compiler that C must have a specific constructor, so that I can call new C, without having to manually resort to reflection?

Comment: The discussion of the same problem here: http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/10685

Answer (score 1):

What about adding `ClassTag` or `TypeTag`? It can be some sort of intermediate solution towards reflection:

```
abstract class Companion[C <: MyObj](implicit ct:ClassTag[C]) {
  def apply(name: String):C = 
    ct.getConstructor(classOf[String]).invoke(Array[Any](name)).asInstanceOf[C]
}
```

(not sure in the exact syntax)